# Inline variable substitution QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have a model and want to output all layers to the same geopackage.

I've added a String Input, named it workspace, set a default value like:

```
C:\GIS\folder\data.gpkg
```

And try to use it in output of algorithms:

```
@workspace|layername='simplified'
```

When I execute the model get the error:

> “.” files are not supported as outputs for this algorithm

Is this possible, (like in ArcGIS `%ws%\simplified`)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a File/Folder input, name it `workspace`

Set the default value to a existing geopackage, like `/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/testdatabase.gpkg`

Set the processing outputs to `Pre-Calculated Value` and the expression:

```
format( 'ogr:dbname=%1 table=%2 (geom)', @workspace, 'buffered' )
```

Replace buffered with your desired table name.

The expression will create the output string: `'ogr:dbname=/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/testdatabase.gpkg table=buffered (geom)'`

[image]